# Alternatives for static events WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, viewmodel

I was trying to connect two `viewmodels` with each other and ended up using `static events`. Here is overview of what I got.

1. `MainViewModel`
2. `ChildViewModel`

I was trying to instantiate the ChildViewModel in the MainViewModel Constructor

```
ChildViewModel childViewModel;
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        childViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
        childViewModel.TextStatusChanged += ChildViewModel_TextStatusChanged; 
    }
```

But, this approach failed because the `ChildViewModel` instance which was created here is ended up with the scope ending, also the `ChildViewModel` instance which was created in it's related view is completely different than the one I created in the `MainViewModel`.

I then changed this to use Static Events like this

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ChildWindowViewModel.TextStatusChanged += ChildViewModel_TextStatusChanged; 
    }
```

It worked like charm but after after a little read I See that all people telling that static events are bad because they might lead to memory leak.

What alternatives to static events may I use, or how can I attach the same `viewmodel` instance to hold the same event.

Comment: *"ended up with the scope ending"* sounds odd. It should exist as long as the MainWindowViewModel instance, which holds a reference to it. *"the ChildViewModel instance which was created in it's related view"* indicates a programming error. You should not create a view model instance in the view when you already created one in code behind. Instead, access the one in the MainWindowViewModel by exposing it as a property, like `public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; }`

Comment: sounds like MainViewModel should have a collection of ChildViewModel? When you create each child perhaps just pass it the main?

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for your reply, I am not creating any new instances but defining the ChildViewModel in it's related xaml creates a new instance by default and for my point of view I can't reference the already created ChildViewModel from xaml

Comment: *"defining the ChildViewModel in it's related xaml creates a new instance"* - this is exactly what you should not do. Don't define a ChildViewModel in XAML. Besides that, we can't tell you how to access the ChildViewModel because you haven't told us anything about the structure of your application, and how you views are looking like.

Comment: @Clemens Again, thanks for you reply. My views are MainWindow with MainViewModel and Pages with corresponding ViewModels and another Windows with corresponding ViewModel. The scenario I want to achieve is that based on button click in MainWindow, A SecondWindow opens and changing text value in it reflects that change in the MainWindow. As I mentioned before static events achieved what I am seeking but it's not a good approach.

Comment: Sounds like mvvmlight messenger would suit this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26070.communicating-between-classes.aspx Or prism's eventaggregator. Which uses weak events.

Comment: @Clemens Also defining a Window data context in the ChildWindow xaml isn't that creating new instance of the ChildViewModel ?

Comment: If you mean `<Window.DataContext><local:ChildViewModel/></Window.DataContext>`, that creates an instance, yes.

Comment: @Clemens So how can I hook up the already created instance of ChildViewModel that was created in the MainViewModel constructor with the view

Comment: When you create a window, pass the appropriate child view model instance to its DataContext property.

Comment: @Clemens You can add your comments in a separate answer so that I can mark them, too late I know :)

Comment: @Clemens ......

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use an event aggregator.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/812461/Event-Aggregator-Pattern